# in Vimscript (vimL) how do I augment a library's function?

Tags: vim

I have an autoload vim script library that I've gotten form vim.org.  I don't want to change it directly but want to put something in my vimrc that augments one of the functions in that library so that whenever that function is called in that library, my function also gets called.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you will have to patch that function.

You may also automate the process this way:

- move `{rtp}/autoload/path/to/script.vim` to `{rtp}/autoload/path/to/script0.vim`
- apply `:%s/fu\%[nction]!\= *path#path#script#&0#g` in the script moved
- generate your own `{rtp}/autoload/path/to/script.vim` that forwards all calls to the original script.

Comment: I'm trying to switch to use vim-addon-manager for managing my plugins, but I have a custom change to one of them that I don't want to loose.  Maybe I'll just not have vim-addon-manager manage that plugin for me. :/

Comment: Can't you ask the author to open its autoload plugin ?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means.  The plugin is Conque_Shell and I have changed it's autoload/conque_term.vim file...

Comment: I mean to open it to support an external hook. For instance, several of my plugins are opened to hooks, but we cannot think of these hooks before the need arises.

Comment: @ashleydev vim-addon-manager is able to preserve differencies between local version and original version on plugin update, but if they were made after plugin was installed by vim-addon-manager (see `:h vim-addon-manager-do_diff` if you want to disable this functionality).

Comment: @ashleydev: though vim-addon-manager preserves differencies, I suggest you to use source control systems instead: considering that you install your addons to ~/.vam and have `hgsubversion` extension installed and enabled, run `hg clone svn+http://conque.googlecode.com/svn/trunk ~/.vam/Conque_Shell`, do your changes, do `hg commit -R ~/.vam/Conque_Shell -m "Commit message"`, then do `hg merge && hg commit -m Merge` after each plugin update.

Comment: hmm looks like Conque_Shell got hooks 4 days ago, but it's still not in the trunk branch.  http://code.google.com/p/conque/source/detail?r=449